# Fancybox Pop Up Always Display On Top of The Page On Tablet or Mobile Device

Tags: jquery, fancybox, tablet

The Fancybox pop up work as expected on desktop, but while accessing via mobile or tablet device, the pop up always shows at the top of the page.

Say, I scroll the page down, then I click a link that can display the pop up, but the pop up doesn't show, coz it display on top, so I need to scroll up the page.

This is my code

```
jQuery("#popup").fancybox({
    "titlePosition"     : "inside",
    "transitionIn"      : "none",
    "transitionOut"     : "none",
    "centerOnScroll"    : true
});
```

Any help would be apreciated.

Comment: what version of fancybox?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get around this issue, you could use `scrollTop()` to get the vertical scroll position and then set the top margin on `#popup` to that value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
jQuery('.fancy_ajax_close_btn').fancybox({
    minWidth  : '43%',
    maxWidth  : '60%',
    afterLoad : function() {

        var top = ($(window).height() / 2) - ($(".fancybox-wrap").outerHeight() / 2);
        var left = ($(window).width() / 2) - ($(".fancybox-wrap").outerWidth() / 2);
        $(".fancybox-wrap").css({ top: top, left: left});           
    }           

});
```

and in jquery.fancybox.css

```
.fancybox-wrap {
 left: 0;
 z-index: 8020;
 position: absolute;
 width: 200px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Not a perfect solution but for V2.0 its the best one.

Comment: Its a best solution i could find for this version and still it works perfect